# HttpClient post returning Observable on second call in observable chain

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have implemented a post function with the httpClient like this:

```
 return this.http
  .post<any>(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    JSON.stringify(data),
    httpOptions
  )
  .pipe(
    catchError((error: any) => {
      return error;
    })
  );
```

}

whit httpOptions being:

```
var httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
};
```

Depending on the response I get (Im using counter as an example instead of my evaluation implementation) I might have to call the function again. For this Im chaining my observables with pipe(map()) like this:

```
 func(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.counter < 2) {
      return this.post().pipe(
        map(
          (response: any) => {
            this.counter++;
            return this.func();
          },
          (error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

Whit counter initially being:

```
counter: number = 0;
```

Im calling my func() fucntion inside another function like this:

```
  test(): void {
    this.func().subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

The problem I have is that this.http.post() returns an observable instead of the response value the second time i call it inside func(). I cant understand what Im doing wrong. Could anyone help?
You can find my example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmusvr?file=src/app/http.service.ts).

Comment: 1. You can omit HTTP headers and stringifying and just go with a plain object as data. 2. map should be switch to 'mergeMap' so you can unwrap observable. 3. this looks like a bad approach, try 'repeatUntil' operator

Comment: 2nd point - it just for general knowledge. working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjmzw6?file=src/app/http.service.ts